# ubuntu 18.04 systray doesn't exists

Tags: 18.04, system-tray

running

```
gsettings list-recursively net.launchpad.indicator.systemtray
```

i got:

```
No existe el esquema «net.launchpad.indicator.systemtray»
```

I noticed because some applications, like jdownloader have system try icon, but it doesn't show. Oddly, dropbox, yandex and wallch icons are present.

how do i fix it?

Comment: See if this helps: [Indicator icons do not appear after upgrade to Ubuntu 17.10](https://askubuntu.com/questions/966987/indicator-icons-do-not-appear-after-upgrade-to-ubuntu-17-10)

Comment: thanks!! but it seems i don't have any `indicator*` app. installed, since i installed ubuntu from zero

Comment: This is a somewhat involved solution, but it should work: https://askubuntu.com/questions/905858/appindicators-not-working-for-electron-applications-skype-for-linux-discord-et