# Skype indicator missing on 18.04 - Skype bug or related to my particular config?

Tags: indicator, skype, gnome-shell

I installed Skype (using snap) on Bionic (18.04) and it works fine, but no indicator is visible in the top bar. Other applications (e.g. Amarok, Knotes, Veracrypt) don't have this problem.

I have found references to this happening in previous Ubuntu versions, but the suggested solutions (e.g. install `sni-qt`) don't work here, nor does

```
env XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP=GNOME /snap/skype/51/usr/share/skypeforlinux/skypeforlinux
```

as suggested [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/905858/appindicators-not-working-for-electron-applications-skype-for-linux-discord-et).

Am  I the only one with this problem (i.e. is this related to my particular Ubuntu install) or is it a known bug with this version of Skype (8.28.0.41)?

Any suggestions would be appreciated!

Comment: Mine shows at the top

Comment: Pomsky: nope, that doesn't solve the problem. Output of "env" command does contain (among other things) XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP=GNOME but using this as suggested in the quoted post has no effect.

Comment: Aha, okay. I presume you're using the snap version of Skype, probably that's why this trick is not working. This trick works for me all the time with the deb version of Skype (from their official website). Probably better to [edit] and mention explicitly that you're using the snap.

Comment: @pomsky: Output of "env XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP=Unity skypeforlinux" is as follows; (skypeforlinux:29424): LIBDBUSMENU-GTK-WARNING **: Unable to create pixbuf data stream: Unable to load image-loading module: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gdk-pixbuf-2.0/2.10.0/loaders/libpixbufloader-png.so: /snap/core/current/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so.1: version `ZLIB_1.2.9' not found (required by /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpng16.so.16) -- Repeated 6 more times.

Comment: @pomsky: yes, it's the snap version which is the default option in 18.04. I'll give the deb version a try and see if that works.

Comment: @pomsky: Sorry, it took me a while (work getting in the way) but the deb version with the modified XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP works. Tnx!

Comment: I use .deb version and both ways don't work

Answer (score 1):

Simple answer:

```
env XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP=Unity skypeforlinux
```